# Add database to existing SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, database

I've spent a lot of time trying to research outside resources, but different solutions seem to be more involved than I was hoping.

I am trying to achieve the following:

- create simple database on existing SQL instance on this local computer.
- security should just be a simple user name and password
- other options are unnecessary (log, growth, max size, etc)

This is my first attempt at database integration with my program. using SQLite or SMO seemed slightly overwhelming to start. I've been trying to modify this sample code to work:

```
private void createDatabase()
{
    String str;
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=" + serverName + ";Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

    str = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbName + " ON PRIMARY " +
           "(NAME = " + dbName + "_Data, " +
           "FILENAME = 'C:\\" + dbName + ".mdf', " +
           "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
           "LOG ON (NAME = " + dbName + "_Log, " +
           "FILENAME = 'C:\\" + dbName + ".ldf', " +
           "SIZE = 1MB, " +
           "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
           "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to create a simple query string or something to create a database? If there's a better way, that's fine but keep in mind I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible just to start with.

Comment: If you take the SQL generated in `str` and run it in SSMS what happens?

Comment: Suggestion: Try `using` inside a `try-catch` block. Using will close the connection, and if `using` or `.Close()` throws any exception you can catch it `catch` block.

Comment: i get an Access is Denied error. i also cannot create the .mdf file at that location. i do know the creditials to log on to another database in the SQL instance, but don't know how to apply that with me creating a DB. i also don't know where to put the .mdf file or where the other ones are stored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using SMO:

```
    Server server = new Server("servername");
    Database db = new Database(server, "MyDatabaseName");
    db.Create();
```

To build an SMO application, you need to reference the SMO assemblies. Click ‘Add Reference’ and navigate to the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies
```

Add references to these assemblies:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

Add this using statement to the file containing the above code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

On a Side Note:

- [Fixing Slow SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Performance](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/fixing-slow-sql-server-management.html)

Comment: i can't seem to find those references!

i'm using .NET Framwork 4.0, so following this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13755/SMO-Manage-your-SQL-Server i can't find the correct.NET reference.

Comment: how do i check, i have SQL 2008 R2. the microsoft site was not exactly helpful (surprise)

Comment: okay installed the Shared Management Utilities. browsed for and added references for the the assemblies you listed, added these `Usings` for `using Microsoft.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management;`, still get a type or namespace not found error...am i missing something?